# Convolution theorem for generalized functions

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, convolution, deconvolution

The standard convolution theorem says $\mathcal{F}(f*g)=\mathcal{F}(f)\mathcal{F}(g)$, where $f$ and $g$ are both functions.However, it still works for some generalized function, for example, when $f$ is Dirac delta. I am just wondering whether there is a convolution theorem for generalized functions? Thanks!

Comment: Just use the definition of the convolution of a compactly supported distribution with a distribution and the definition of the Fourier transform of a tempered distribution. You'll find that it won't always work because you can't multiply distributions, but this should be clear after going through what I said.

Comment: Many thanks for the clarification! Could you provide an counter example where the convolution theorem does not work? Thanks!